# EMR creates 0 byte files while using HDFS's moveFromLocalFile API

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I'm using EMR to move a folder from local file system to S3 in Spark using fs.moveFromLocalFile API. Everything works fine except a 0-byte file created by EMRFS with name _$folder$ for EVERY folder that is uploaded.

Is there any way to move folders without this dummy file creation for every folder? (other than manually deleting this file). Also, why is this dummy file created? I'm currently using s3:// protocol recommended by EMR team.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the mkdir() function usually called for local file systems or hdfs will result in an s3 empty file being created with the name of the mkdir folder and appended by _$folder$. In S3, there is no concept of an "empty folder" because you cannot have a key (pathname) with a null value (the file).

In a perfect world, mkdir(s3://bucket/path) should be a noop.

Comment: it's trickier than you think. We need to (a) make sure that you can't mkdir under a file and (b) that empty directories exist when you do an ls. It's there in the expected semantics of an fs that `mkdir path; ls path` returns something successful. The FS clients do delete the marker files when things underneath are created

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about EMR fs; this sounds like the same extension used by The S3n client. These files are stripped in the client when listing/stat-ing paths.

ASF's S3a creates one with a "/" suffix.